# Web Sockets - Send messages to all clients

Tags: sockets, websocket, phpwebsocket

I am completely new to Web Sockets, I have applied them to my chat so now it looks something like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var connection = new WebSocket("ws://echo.websocket.org"); //"public" websocket server
     connection.onopen = function () {
        console.log('Connection: OK.');
     };
     connection.onerror = function (error) {
       console.log(Error: ' + error); 
     };
     connection.onmessage = function () {
        $('#chatbox').load('/chatbox.php');
     };
$(document).ready(function() {  

    $('#chatOK').click(function(event) {
     //something
     connection.send('Get new messages.'); 


    });     
});         
</script>
```

It works well for one client, when I enter message it updates the chatbox but only mine, but I want to update it for everyone (=all users who have opened chat window). So how can I send with WebSockets message to all clients?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this with the websocket.org echo server - this just echos whatever you send it back to the sender.

You need a server which handles the distribution to all clients. This is easiest done using the Publish & Subscribe messaging pattern:

All chat messages are published to a common topic, e.g. "myChatRoom_1".

All connected clients indicate to the server that they are interested in messages to "myChatRoom_1" (that's the subscription).

Now when the server receives a published event for "myChatRoom_1" it can distribute it to all subscribers.

Take a look at [this demo](https://demo.crossbar.io/demo/chat/index.html) to see this in action.

It's based on [Crossbar.io](http://crossbar.io), an open source application router, which does PubSub out of the box, without an additional backend. So if you used this, you'd need to implement just the changes to your browser chat clients.
If you want to integrate with your PHP backend (e.g. since this stores the chat messages somewhere), there is a [PHP library](https://github.com/voryx/Thruway) for connecting to Crossbar.io as well.

Full disclosure: I work for Tavendo, who are the maintainers of the Crossbar.io project.

Comment: Thanks @gzost but I already solved it, using modified phpwebsockets. But I have another problem, now if I want it to work I must run the websocket server by submitting `php -q /server.php` to the CMD. But I don't know how will I run it online, on some hosting. Is there a way to have some php file running nonstop in background?

Comment: I've no idea about anything PHP - sorry :(